# storing live data in Mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, arduino, database

I am pushing data to a server using an API from a website. Every time my arduino detects a pulse it sends it to COSM. And by using a trigger, the data goes to my server. I was initially writing the data into a .txt file and a Json object, but now I want to start implementing mongo to have different collections.

For some reason the data is not being transmitted to my server after I added the Mongo connection when I tried to write it as a Mongo collection. I want to be able to write down the information in Mongo directly and avoid creating files.

Any suggestion is more than welcome, here is the code:

```
<?php

// Creating a data base in Mongodb to store my information from my $jsonFile
$connection = new MongoClient(); //Connect to mongo
$db = $connection -> qandm; // select my DB which is called qandM
$collection = $db -> pulseData;

//Gets all the information from Cosm
$pulse = $_POST['body'];

//access and open a file
//echo $pulse;

//Converts the data into PHP arrays
$pulseObj = json_decode($pulse, true);

//Parse through the specific information from the array and gets each piece of information in an array
$userName = $pulseObj["triggering_datastream"]["id"];
$dataTime= $pulseObj["triggering_datastream"]["at"];
$dataValue= $pulseObj["triggering_datastream"]["value"]["value"];


//Writes all the data coming from COSM
$file = fopen("data.txt", "a+");//a+ give the option to have the cursor at the end to access the file read and write it
    /*  $pulse.="\r\n"; */
fwrite($file, $pulse);//takes incoming data and writes it in the file
fclose($file);

//Opens a new .txt file and writes the values that we selected before into our file
$string = $userName." ".$dataTime." ".$dataValue." \r\n";
//error_log allows me to see in my Apache log server the information that I'm printing
error_log($string);

//Write all the information I parsed in my three variables in a new file
$file2 = fopen("rawData.txt", "a+");
fwrite($file2,$string);
fclose($file2);

//json sample

//Inputs the data from the time and the pulse value into a json object
$json = array("User" => $userName, "timestamp"=> $dataTime, "value"=> $dataValue);

//Opens a new json object
$jsonFile = fopen("data.json", "a+");

//Writes the data of our new arrayed information into the open json object
fwrite($jsonFile, json_encode($json));
fclose($jsonFile);




//A loop to populate
foreach($json as $data){
    $collection->insert($data);

}

//find the data I just stored
$cursor = $collection->find();

//Output it in a UL
echo "<p> My Pulse </p>";

echo '<ul>';
foreach($cursor as $doc){

    echo' <li> My pulse is: '.$doc['value'];

}
 echo '</ul>';


/*$data = "data.txt";
$fh = fopen($data, "w") or die ("can't open file");
$data = json_encode($_POST);
fwrite($fh, $data);
fclose($fh);*/

//print_r($file);



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely the source of your problems:

```
//A loop to populate
foreach($json as $data){
    $collection->insert($data);

}
```

You are iterating over your $json array and passing the values (but not the keys) to the insert method of MongoCollection.  According to the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongocollection.insert.php) this method expects an object or an array.  Based on what I understand your code to be trying to do this foreach loop should be replaced with the following:

```
$collection->insert($json);
```

This will create a mongo object resembling your array. Your code currently is attempting to insert the values of each array element as an individual entry.

Comment: Sam, Thanks so much for your reply, what a little mistake I had. For some reason what I wanted to do with the foreach() was to assign a unique _id to each coming string from my pulse sensor, which sends 3 values. But this works great! Thanks again!